# Prove or disprove convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I don't know how to prove or disprove convergence of the following. Which convergence test do I need to use?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln^2n}$$

Comment: It converges. Integral Test (easiest) or Cauchy Condensation.  By the way, the sum should not start at $1$.

Comment: can you write the solution?

Comment: @F.leon Try u-sub $lnn=u$ and see what happens when integrating

Comment: Someone may write a full solution soon. But if not, imranfat's hint comes close to finishing. The integral $\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln^2 x}\,dx$ can be evaluated explicitly using $u=\ln x$.

Comment: You can find many solved exampled of series in the [catalog of series](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/series/)

Comment: By the way, for series whose general term is of the form $\frac{1}{n^\alpha \ln^\beta n}$, a general and quite simple criterion is known -- this is a ["séris de Bertrand"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) (it's unclear to me if an English name exists, and even if this is taught as theorem in te UK/US, however.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}<\ln2+\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}dx=\ln 2 - \left[1\over\ln x\right]_2^\infty=\ln 2+\frac{1}{\ln 2}$$